# Alphabet Filter for Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, indexing, alphabet

I'm new to rails, so forgive me if there is an easy answer. I'm trying to implement an "Alphabet Index" for a table in rails. I want to be able to click on a letter and have the table refresh - containing only the data on which the first letter of the `last_name` column matches the letter clicked.

My first thought was to generate an array of letter from the database

```
@visitor_array = []
@v = Visitor.all
@v.each do |visitor|
    @visitor_array << visitor.last_name[0,1]
    end
@visitor_array.sort!
@visitor_array.uniq!
```

This code gives me an array which has one of each of the first letters. I used this as my "alphabet". On my view I have the following code

```
<% @visitor_array.each do |visitor| %>
  <%= link_to visitor, alphasort(visitor) %>
<% end %>
```

The thought here is to run a helper function when the letter is clicked. But here is where I'm stuck.

---

**UPDATE:**

Okay, thanks to the comments below, I was able to figure it out. In case anyone else was wondering, this is how it was accomplished.

**CONTROLLER**

```
# Create array consisting of the first letter of every visitor's last name
@visitor_array = []
@v = Visitor.all
@v.each do |visitor|
    @visitor_array << visitor.last_name[0,1]
    end
#Sort array alphabetically in ASC order
@visitor_array.sort!
#Remove duplicate elements
@visitor_array.uniq!


if (params[:letter] != nil)
@visitors = Visitor.order("last_name ASC").where("last_name like ?", params[:letter] +"%" )
else
@visitors = Visitor.order("last_name ASC")
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<% @visitor_array.each do |letter| %>
  <%= link_to letter, :controller => "visitors" , :letter => letter %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the list of results for a specific letter:

```
visitors = Visitor.order("last_name ASC").where("last_name like '?'", letter)
```

Then on your view:

```
<% @visitor_array.each do |visitor| %>

    <%= link_to visitor(visitor) %>

<% end %>
```

The syntax might be slightly off but the fundamental idea is there.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the last line though...

Comment: The WHERE clause in the above statement can be improved to be `last_name like '?%'`, so it only starts with the letter, assuming the Rails version works like normal SQL.

Comment: Alright, so after a little tweaking, this line of code works.
  `@visitors = Visitor.order("last_name ASC").where("last_name like ?", letter +"%" )`

However, the link part is not working. I don't want the table to be filtered until the letter is clicked, but if I put that code in the controller, then my table loads as filtered. I tried putting it into a helper method, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Yes, I would assume that if you receive no letter in the request you'd just do @visitors = Visitor.order("last_name ASC") and leave the where off...

Comment: @Karl: thanks, good catch. it was in my head that way, but somewhere between there and the keyboard that little % went off the rails...

Comment: Okay, so im trying to pass the letter as a hash back to the controller when you click on the link  `<%= link_to letter, "visitors" , :letter => letter %>` That way I can use :letter for this conditional statement `if (params[:letter] != nil)`. But it doesn't seem to be storing the hash.